# What is the relation between LSA and LSASS in Windows?

Tags: windows

I know that LSA and LSASS stands for "Local Security Authority" And "Local Security Authority Subsystem Service", respectively.

The LSASS is an executable within Windows that stores credentials in memory etc, both for local and domain users (right?)

Is LSASS merely an implementation of LSA, or what is the relationship between these two?

Comment: Where are you seeing LSA? If you have a process running e.g. "lsa.exe" it could be malware masquerading as a valid system function.

Comment: I'm not seing LSA running. It is just a concept, I often see used articles etc.

Comment: ok, then I can answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is "LSA" the concept, and "lsass.exe", a process that implements many of the functions of LSA. Besides "authentication" itself (validating user's credentials against the SAM database) this does include storage of credentials, secure key storage (if your system has no other place to store them), and so on. If you have auditing enabled on e.g. files, it is the Lsass.exe that formats and sends the entries to the security log.

btw, in a domain, when you log into a domain account, the actual job of authentication of course happens on the domain controller. The authentication credentials are then still stored in your local machine.

There are also APIs whose names start with "Lsa", and these provide interfaces to LSA functions.

The term "ss" for "subsystem" is more jargon. There is no clear definition I've ever seen that explains exactly what in Windows gets named a "subsystem". In the case of lsass.exe the term "subsystem" may refer to the fact that this process implements several different upper-level functions, even a few services. But that explanation doesn't fit, for example, csrss.exe, the "helper" process for Win32 APIs.

On a Windows 10 system with modern hardware, with virtualization features turned on in the firmware, you may also see the LSAiso.exe process running. This is "LSA isolated". It is a "trustlet" - Microsoft jargon for an executable running in "VTL 1", virtual trust level 1, in a mechanism called "virtualization-based security". VBS is very clever and effective. In this design, things like the credential store are stored in areas of memory where they cannot be accessed from "normal" (VTL 0) user or kernel mode. VBS gets turned on automatically with a late-enough version of Windows 10 and if your CPU supports it.

Comment: Thank you, so LSA is a specification that LSASS.exe partially implements? With regards to LSAiso.exe - is it meant to replace LSASS.exe?  If users nor the kernel can access LSAiso.exe, what can then then access it?

Comment: "LSA is a specification..." I would say several specifications, but you could think of it that way, yes. Another way to think of it is that it's a sort of catch-all for a lot of security-related functions and services that need their own process context but don't necessarily need to be in the same process as each other - otoh there'd be no benefit in separate ones. Re VTL1, VTL 0 (where the "ordinary" OS lives) can't access the memory of VTL 1, not even through page table manipulation - but there are IPC mechanisms whereby VTL 0 functions can invoke things implemented in VTL 1.